# How to properly seed bomb a particular area with drones?

Tags: trees, seeds, planting

I searched for a long time on internet but can't find a perfect tutorial on the whole process. I found one for making seed bombs: https://www.gardenista.com/posts/diy-wildflower-seed-bombs/

I wanted to know about the complications involving planting seed bombs with drones, is it just flying the drone to an appropriate spot on the land with proper altitude and just dropping the seed bombs or there are problems to this approach?

Answer (score 2):

The issues as I see them would be as follows:

1. Weight - these are going to weigh at least 1 oz - likely more. I think you'd quickly reach most drone's carrying capacity with relatively few "bombs." This would necessitate many trips to cover even relatively small areas.
2. Structural integrity of the "bomb" - depending on soil structure and moisture content, these could "bombs" could break on impact even from relatively low altitudes. The point of the "bomb" is that in it's initial configuration it can hold a fair amount of water - enough to facilitate germination. If the "bomb" ruptures on impact with the ground after being dropped from a drone, then you would be left with seed and soil sitting on open ground and would lose the benefit of the "bomb" in the first place.
3. Distribution - spacing isn't all that imperative if you are putting out enough of these things, but even limiting delivery to a defined space will be difficult. The GPS in most drone are not precise enough to permit landing your "bombs" within a 1' area, so you'd probably want to seed at a higher density than required.
4. Does the drone have an apparatus that would release single or several "bombs" at a time - rather than the entire batch at once?

I am interested to know why you would want to plant with a drone rather than just walk to the area in question to plant - unless you don't have access to said area for some reason or don't want to be associated with any kind of planting occurring at said location.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take these into consideration. As for why, I need to cover a large area of land for reforestation and trying to find a quicker way. Do you know any other faster and quicker way?

Comment: volunteer help would seem like the best option: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/india-plant-66-million-trees-12-hours-environment-campaign-madhya-pradesh-global-warming-climate-a7820416.html

Comment: @AashishGangwani You're planting tree seeds?

Comment: Make them egg shaped to withstand falls!

Comment: @ThatIdiot thanks, I will look into that approach

Comment: @Shule I am thinking of both plant and tree seeds :)